# Figbib not working?

Tags: floats, texmaker

I'm new to TeX and didn't find my answer anywhere else. I use TeXmaker and I want to use `figbib` for managing my figures. Unfortunately, I don't even get the sample file working. I followed the steps provided in the documentation, i.e. use `latex, then`bibtex`, then`latex` at most 3 times until all cross-references has been updated. Unfortunately, it still says "Fig. ???". There are no figures visible. What did I do wrong?

When using `BibTex` it reads this:

> This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: figbib_sample.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file figbib_sample.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file figbib_sample.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file figbib_sample.aux (There were 3 error messages)

I didn't change anything, just extracted it from the .zip. Therefore I think that I can ignore this, but maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is that Texmaker runs BibTeX on the wrong file. The BibTeX command in Texmaker will run

```
bibtex filename.aux
```

but for `figbib` you should run

```
bibtex filename.figbib
```

You can run the above command in a terminal if you prefer that, but you can also add a custom compilation command in Texmaker:

1. Go to User --> Commands --> Edit User commands
2. In an available slot, write the command

   ```
    bibtex %.figbib
   ```

   and give it a suitable name, e.g. figbibtex. The `%` is a placeholder for the basename of the file, i.e. filename without extension.

Now you can run the proper command with the given keyboard shortcut (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>).

Comment: Works better, but I still can't see any images. Now it looks like [this](http://speedy.sh/QMnNZ/figbib-sample.pdf). Using `bibtex`, there is no error. `LaTex` tells me "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in pragraph at lines 1--32". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user41123 I don't really know what causes that. It works fine here with `pdflatex` - `figbibtex` - `pdflatex` - `pdflatex` - `pdflatex`.

Comment: I just deleted all of my files, extracted them again and now it works just fine. Thanks a lot!